# Extract indexes and dates of first and last non na values with summarize_all AND format output

Tags: r, dplyr, na, summarize

I have a tibble df with various time series (columns variables, rows observations for various dates), the dates are listed in the first column called Date. I want to extract the indexes and the corresponding dates of the first and last non-na observations for each column and then save these to a new data frame that has one column for each time series and the indexes and dates in four rows.

I got this far:

```
df %>% summarise_all(.funs = list(first.idx = ~min(which(!is.na(.))),  last.idx = ~max(which(!is.na(.)))) )
```

but this works only for the indexes and I get two columns for each time series and function, so one row. How to proceed? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

 df %>% 
   mutate(across(-Date, list(first.idx = ~as.character(min(which(!is.na(.)))),
                               last.idx = ~as.character(max(which(!is.na(.))))))) %>% 
   mutate(across(contains("_"), ~ifelse(. == row_number(), as.character(Date), NA), .names = "date_{.col}")) %>% 
   fill(starts_with("date"), .direction = "updown") %>% 
   slice(1) %>% 
   select(-c(Date, A, B)) %>% 
   pivot_longer(everything())
```

```
  name             value     
  <chr>            <chr>     
1 A_first.idx      1         
2 A_last.idx       9         
3 B_first.idx      4         
4 B_last.idx       9         
5 date_A_first.idx 2022-01-01
6 date_A_last.idx  2022-01-09
7 date_B_first.idx 2022-01-04
8 date_B_last.idx  2022-01-09
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer, which was pertinent to my question. I realized that as usual there's another (better) way altogether without using `summarize_all`:

```
df %>% mutate(Index = 1:nrow(df)) %>% 
pivot_longer(!c(Date,Index),names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% na.omit() %>% 
  summarize(first = min(Date),last = max(Date), 
            first_idx = min(Index),last_idx = max(Index))
```